# name '__current_graph' is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

When I reproduce the result of a paper, I creatde a virtualenv "side" according to the requirement. But when I run the code in Jupyter notebook I still meet some problems.
I do not know what is wrong with the "_base.py".
Here is the error:

---

```
~\.conda\envs\side\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in 
result_iterator()
554                 for future in fs:
555                     if timeout is None:
--> 556                         yield future.result()
557                     else:
558                         yield future.result(end_time - 
time.time())

~\.conda\envs\side\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in 
result(self, timeout)
403                 raise CancelledError()
404             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 405                 return self.__get_result()
406             else:
407                 raise TimeoutError()

~\.conda\envs\side\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in 
__get_result(self)
355     def __get_result(self):
356         if self._exception:
--> 357             raise self._exception
358         else:
359             return self._result

NameError: name '__current_graph' is not defined
```

Comment: Please include a mcve to reproduce this error.

Comment: update: problem solved.  I add a definition of "__current_graph" before the function which uses this variable